# How do I write a proof that $G^C$ (G complement) has a Euler cycle in a general way?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, graph-theory, proof-writing, eulerian-path

So I'm basically failing my discrete mathematics class, with Graph Theory, because I don't know how to define something generally and not specifically, and all our teacher does is read the textbook and not answer our emails. Anyway I want to learn:

For Instance, One of our proofs is:
`Let G be a C7 graph (A circuit graph with 7 vertices). Prove that G^C (G complement) has a Euler Cycle`

Well I know that An Euler cycle is a cycle that contains all the edges in a graph (and visits each vertex at least once).

And obviously the complement of G would be all the same vertices, but not using any of the same edges and connecting all the ones that weren't connected.

Also its not mentioned, but I think were assuming that G has a Euler cycle and you just need to prove that G^C also has that Euler cycle. Of course I could do this specifically by mentioning a specific example, but I'm lost on how to write the proof.

Comment: And what was your question, exactly?

Comment: As stated, the problem does not *assume* $G$ has an Euler cycle, though it does since it is a cycle graph.

Comment: If you can list a specific example, that would be a proof.  You are asked to prove that an Euler cycle exists.  Obviously, if you exhibit an example, then an Euler cycle exists, namely the example you exhibited.

Comment: You might try to work out a smaller example.  The complete graph $\mathbf{K_5}$ on five vertices, separated into two $5$-cycles, is particularly easy to visualize.  Writing the proof in an "elegant" way will probably hinge on choosing a convenient labeling of the vertices, i.e. numbering them so you can show each each is being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asked to prove the existence of an Euler cycle *in a specific graph*. Just give one and you're done. This might be a bit tedious as we have a lot of edges.

You can also quote a theorem:

> $G$ has an Euler cycle iff it is connected and all vertices have even degree.

Which I hope has been covered in your course.

Well, in $C_7$ every vertex has degree 2 (out of the 6 connections they could have had), so in the complement of $C_7$ every vertex has degree $4$ (so all even). This complement is clearly connected (If the cycle is $1 \to 2 \to 3  \to \ldots \to 6 \to 7 \to 1$: the component of $1$ contains $\{1,3,4,5,6\}$ directly and next $1$ and $7$ in two steps via $3$ resp. $5$ and so all points are in one component) so the theorem applies and the complement of $C_7$ is Eulerian.